# Fetch data on both client and server side in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, next.js, seo

I need to fetch data with a third-party API in some of my components in the NextJS project

I want the server to pre-render the component using that API for SEO.
but after that while user is interacting with the app, the component props should fetch on the client-side.

I'm able to implement this behavior by using NextJS `getInitialProps` method. but in official NextJS documentation it's recommended to use `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` .

I want to know What is the recommended way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle size is smaller when we use **getServerSideProps** instead of **getInitialProps** as the getServerSideProps execute the code on the server not on the browser.

Read more about the difference between these two [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11211).

Answer (score 0):

Next.js docs [says](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps):

> If you're using Next.js 9.3 or newer, we recommend that you use
> getStaticProps or getServerSideProps instead of getInitialProps.
>
> These new data fetching methods allow you to have a granular choice
> between static generation and server-side rendering. Learn more on the
> documentation for Pages and Data Fetching.

You should use getStaticProps if:

> - The data required to render the page is available at build time ahead    of a user’s request.
> - The data comes from a headless CMS.
> - The data can be publicly cached (not user-specific).
> - The page must be pre-rendered (for SEO) and be very fast — getStaticProps generates HTML and JSON files, both of which can be
>   cached by a CDN for performance.
>
> When should I use getServerSideProps? You should use
> getServerSideProps only if you need to pre-render a page whose data
> must be fetched at request time. Time to first byte (TTFB) will be
> slower than getStaticProps because the server must compute the result
> on every request, and the result cannot be cached by a CDN without
> extra configuration.
>
> If you don’t need to pre-render the data, then you should consider
> fetching data on the client side. Click here to [learn more](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fetching-data-on-the-client-side).

Answer (score 0):

If you already know how many pages your website will contain then go with *Static Site Generation* i.e use `getStaticProps`. This will pre-generate all the pages in advance during build time.

**Example** A portfolio website where the content is mostly static.

***NOTE***:- With getStaticProps any changes made to your website won't be reflected you need to re-deploy in order to see the changes.

So if your portfolio also consists of a blog then `getStaticProps` won't be an ideal solution, instead you can use *Incremental Static Regeneration* by adding a revalidate key in the `getStaticProps` function which implies that re-generate the page on every request at most every X-seconds.

Now if you need to pre-render for every request OR you need access to request object for example to set cookies then *Server Side Rendering* is an option use `getServerSideProps` function. **getServerSideProps runs only on the server and not during the build process**

For client side data fetching you can use the useEffect hook or the [swr](https://swr.vercel.app/) hook provided by NEXT JS.

So in your case,
If you are using client side data fetching then probably it doesn't make any sense to use `getServerSideProps` in conjunction, unless you need that request response object.

So you can combine Client Side Data Fetching with getStaticProps (most probably with that revalidate key).